# Twilio - Single Campaign - Multiple Numbers - Unique Webhooks

Tags: twilio, webhooks

I have an application that uses voice and sms services. The current phone number is registered under a campaign and approved for 10AP2-DLC. I want to spin up another copy of the application but isolate it from the existing one. When I attempted this originally, I added another phone number and my current application began using the new number. I don't want that to happen. I would like a second phone number under an existing campaign to use different webhooks. Is that possible?

Thanks for all your help.